# How to sum double variables obtained from a splitted string

Tags: c#, string, math, double

I would like to make a tool to calculate standard deviation.

Since I wanted the user to put all the values from the distribution in the same textbox, I had to make a string.

I chose to split it up using this method:

```css
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };

 string values = richTextBox1.Text;

 string[] numberCount = values.Split(delimiterChars);


  foreach (string s in numberCount)
  {
   Convert.ToDouble(s); 
   
  }
```

However, when I try doing a mathematical operation with '*s*', such as `MessageBox.Show(s -s);` inside the `foreach (string s in numberCount) {` it gets highlighted with a red squiggly and then tells me it can't apply operations to 's' and 's' because they are of string type.

My question is, why does it tell me that 's' is a string even though i converted it to double using `Convert.ToDouble(s);` ?
And how can I make this work to sum up all the values that were splitted in the 'value' variable ?

Thanks in advance,
JSGarden

P.S.: The source is available over at [github.com/jsgarden/ecartMoyen](http://www.github.com/jsgarden/ecartMoyen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
string[] numberCount = values.Split(delimiterChars);
double sum = numberCount.Select(s => double.Parse(s)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDouble(s);` does not convert `s` to Double but it returns double value converted from string `s`. You need to store the returned value to some other `double` variable to perform mathematical operations on it.

```
string values = richTextBox1.Text;
string[] numberCount = values.Split(delimiterChars);
double totalValue = 0;

foreach (string s in numberCount)
{
   var doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(s); 
   totalValue += doubleValue;
   MessageBox.Show(doubleValue - doubleValue);
}
```